# Не получается использовать ADB в Abdroid Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-adb

Использую плагин ADB WIFI

Попробовал запустить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вылетело:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее предпринял следующие действия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скрина, это ни к чему не привело. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: Что за IP вы используете? Это ваше локальное устройство? ПОчему IP выходит из диапазона локальных устройств? Судя по скрину, доступа к порту у IP - нету.

Comment: ip - публичный адрес

Comment: Он вообще проброшен, что бы подключаться к нему? (удаленный порт)

Comment: @kotleni, я в этом не очень разбираюсь, пожалуйста, объясните подробнее

Comment: Подключите все устройства в одну сеть, и используйте локальный IP вашего устройства. Еще, adb over wifi включен в "для разработчиков" / или запущен нужный софт? Android не раздает по стандарту WifiADB.

Comment: попробовал использовать adb connect 192.168.1.2, вроде получилось. сейчас попробую запусить приложение в Android Studio с помощью adb

Comment: @kotleni, всё отлично, приложение запускается, спасибо за Ваши комментрии. Оформите их, пожалуйста, в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте локальный `IP` вашего устройства вместо публичного (устройства должны быть в одной сети), что бы вы могли к нему подключиться.

*Так же не стоит забывать об ADB сервере over Wifi.*

Answer (score 0):

В дополнении к ответу @kotleni:
В мобильном приложении ADB wireless by Henry можно узнать адрес, который Вам нужно использовать